# std functional wrapper of const member function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int get_num(int i) { return num_;}
    void set_num(int i) { num_ = i;}
    int num_;
};
int main() {
    std::function<int(const Foo *, int)> f_get_num;
    f_get_num = &Foo::get_num;
    return 0;
}
```

This will generate a error, `error: invalid conversion from ‘const Foo*’ to ‘Foo*’ [-fpermissive]` at line `f_get_num = &Foo::get_num`. `Foo::get_num` type is `int (Foo:: *fp)(int)`. Can anybody explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think `get_num` has the signature `int(const Foo *, int)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call non-`const` functions on `const` objects. You can pass `const Foo*` to `f_get_num`, but `Foo::get_num` takes non-const implicit `this`.

The following two calls are just as illegal:

```
Foo foo;
Foo const* const_ptr = &foo;

const_ptr->get_num(42);
f_get_num(const_ptr, 42); // results in const_ptr->get_num(42)
```

You can declare your `get_num` to be `const`:

```
int get_num(int i) const { return num_;}
```

And then your code will work correctly.

The other way is to make your `f_get_num` take non-`const` parameter, but that's not the way to go when your function is a getter and shouldn't modify the object.

```
std::function<int(Foo*, int)> f_get_num;
f_get_num = &Foo::get_num;
```